# Отображаются ненужные скобки и кавычки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Декодирую JSON-запрос с сайта в переменную, всё получается, но если к print подставить сразу несколько переменных"print("first: {a}, secondDecode{b})" - то первая переменная отображается нормально, а вторая таким образом" ['Привет мир'] ", если писать просто: (print('secondDecode{b}' - то вывод будет нормальный, то есть: Привет мир.

***Как убрать чертовы скобки и кавычки?***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете предоставить пример вашей json и кода, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил фотографию к основному вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему!

```
 secondDecode = lastperevoddecode["text"]
```

заменил на:

```
 text = lastperevoddecode["text"][0]
```

Исходя из фотографии выше .